# Make UIProgressView as a count down timer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiprogressview, uiprogressbar

I've implemented a UIProgressView as a count down timer, its value is decreased from 1.0 to 0.0 in 1.5 seconds.

It already worked but the problem is the time it took was longer than 1.5 
seconds, it was about 2.0 - 2.5 seconds until the progress view value reach 0.0

For it to run in just 1.5, I decreased the value of the progress by 0.001 each time it's called. The decrease method is call after 0.0015 second interval.

Below is how I do it. I don't know if there's anything wrong that make it run longer than just 1.5 seconds?

```
- (void)decreaseProgress {
    if (currentProgress > 0.0000f) {
        currentProgress -= 0.001f;
        [_timeLineProgress setProgress:currentProgress animated:YES];

        [self performSelector:@selector(decreaseProgress) withObject:self afterDelay:0.0015 inModes:@[NSDefaultRunLoopMode]];
    } else {
        [self stopTimer];
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use an NSTimer instead and base the progress on actual elapsed time.

Comment: @rmaddy will it make any big differences? Because I did use an NSTimer but still got the same problem.

Comment: That's why the progress needs to be based on actual elapsed time and not some incremented value.

Comment: @rmaddy do you have any example code or some links? it might help. You can post it as answer and I'll accept it if it does help me to solve this problem

Comment: Can't you achieve this with just animating the progress from 1.0 to 0.0 in 1.5 seconds?

Comment: @VinayJain thanks for your comment, but I don't get it? That's what I'm doing, it just didn't run in 1.5 seconds, but about 2-3 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to update the progress view 1000 times in 1.5 seconds. That's way too fast, since the screen only updates 60 times per second. In other words, you're updating the progress bar more than 10 times between each time that the progress bar is actually redrawn on the screen.

Instead I would suggest 15 updates at 0.1 second intervals, and change the progress bar by 1/15 each time.

One way to check how well the code is performing is to use the `CACurrentMediaTime` function to get timestamps. Here's some sample code that demonstrates how to do that. The `progressStart` variable is the timestamp when the button press event occurred, and the `NSLog` prints the amount of time elapsed relative to the start time.

An important feature of the code is that the `performSelector` method is called as early as possible in the `updateProgress` method, to minimize slippage.

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    CFTimeInterval progressStart;
    int progressCount;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *progressView;
@end

- (void)updateProgress
{
    if ( progressCount > 0 )
        [self performSelector:@selector(updateProgress) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];

    self.progressView.progress = progressCount / 15.0;
    NSLog( @"%2d %.3lf", progressCount, CACurrentMediaTime() - progressStart );
    progressCount--;
}

- (IBAction)someButtonPressed
{
    self.progressView.progress = 1.0;
    progressStart = CACurrentMediaTime();
    progressCount = 15;
    [self updateProgress];
}
```

And here are the results from a typical run

```
2015-07-01 13:05:57.610 Progress[8354:907] 15 0.000
2015-07-01 13:05:57.711 Progress[8354:907] 14 0.101
2015-07-01 13:05:57.813 Progress[8354:907] 13 0.203
2015-07-01 13:05:57.914 Progress[8354:907] 12 0.304
2015-07-01 13:05:58.015 Progress[8354:907] 11 0.405
2015-07-01 13:05:58.116 Progress[8354:907] 10 0.506
2015-07-01 13:05:58.218 Progress[8354:907]  9 0.608
2015-07-01 13:05:58.319 Progress[8354:907]  8 0.709
2015-07-01 13:05:58.420 Progress[8354:907]  7 0.810
2015-07-01 13:05:58.520 Progress[8354:907]  6 0.910
2015-07-01 13:05:58.621 Progress[8354:907]  5 1.011
2015-07-01 13:05:58.722 Progress[8354:907]  4 1.112
2015-07-01 13:05:58.823 Progress[8354:907]  3 1.213
2015-07-01 13:05:58.924 Progress[8354:907]  2 1.314
2015-07-01 13:05:59.024 Progress[8354:907]  1 1.415
2015-07-01 13:05:59.125 Progress[8354:907]  0 1.515
```

Note that the `performSelector:afterDelay` method has about 1 millisecond of slippage on each event. The total slippage was 15 milliseconds. The device screen update rate is 60 frames/sec, which is 16.7 msec/frame. So the total slippage was less than one frame time, and won't be noticeable to the user.

As rmaddy pointed out in the comments, using an `NSTimer` allows you to avoid most of the slippage. However, the last timer event could still slip by an arbitrary amount of time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I just tried you suggestion but the progress bar still run in 2 seconds. I don't know why?

Comment: It depends on what else the system is doing. The `performSelector:afterDelay` method only specifies a minimum delay. The actual delay could be longer if the system is busy.

Comment: So there isn't any way to make it run exactly 1.5 seconds?

Comment: Thanks so much for your detail code and log. I've implemented as you said and it still ran a bit longer than 1.5 seconds but that was acceptable in my case.

Answer (score 3):

To animate the progress, try this code in your decreaseProgress method

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{
        [_timeLineProgress setProgress:0.0 animated:YES];
    }];
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution Vinay. I think this would work, but I have a few other action while the progress is running, this way it could animate smoothly but I won't control it overall, something like reset the progress while it's running.